# Json parsing with Linux shell script

Tags: json, shell

Here is the json file I want to parse. I specially need the json objects inside the json array. Shell script is the only tool I can use right now.

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "author": {
        "value": "plugin-demo Administrator",
        "origin": "http://localhost:8080/webservice/person/18"
      },
      "creator": {
        "value": "plugin-demo Administrator",
        "origin": "http://localhost:8080/webservice/person/18"
      },
      "creationDate": "2015-11-04T15:14:18.000+0600",
      "lastModifiedDate": "2015-11-04T15:14:18.000+0600",
      "model": "http://localhost:8080/plugin-editorial/model/281/football",
      "payload": [
        {
          "name": "basic",
          "value": "Real Madrid are through"
        }
      ],
      "publishDate": "2015-11-04T15:14:18.000+0600"
    },
    {
      "author": {
        "value": "plugin-demo Administrator",
        "origin": "http://localhost:8080/webservice/person/18"
      },
      "creator": {
        "value": "plugin-demo Administrator",
        "origin": "http://localhost:8080/webservice/person/18"
      },
      "creationDate": "2015-11-04T15:14:18.000+0600",
      "lastModifiedDate": "2015-11-04T15:14:18.000+0600",
      "model": "http://localhost:8080/plugin-editorial/model/281/football",
      "payload": [
        {
          "name": "basic",
          "value": "Real Madrid are through"
        }
      ],
      "publishDate": "2015-11-04T15:14:18.000+0600"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I do it in shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something, anything other than shell.

Since the original answer I've found [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
jq '.entries[0].author.value' /tmp/data.json 
"plugin-demo Administrator"
```

Install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

```
node -e 'console.log(require("./data.json").entries[0].author.value)'
```

Install [`jsawk`](https://github.com/micha/jsawk)

```
cat data.json | jsawk 'return this.entries[0].author.value'
```

Install [`Ruby`](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/)

```
ruby -e 'require "json"; puts JSON.parse(File.read("data.json"))["entries"][0]["author"]["value"]'
```

Just don't try and parse it in shell script.